# Slim Eloquent Relation does not work properly

Tags: php, eloquent, orm, slim, relation

I am making some crud operations with Slim3 Framework. I made some stuff on it. I made 2 tables that are post and category tables. I am trying to relate 2 tables with Eloquent. But Output is just only showing the first related rows.

For example, I have 2 records with same category and output only shows the first record with related fields.

What am i missing?

```
<?php
namespace App\Models;
class Yazi extends \Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model{
    protected $table = "yazilar";
    public function kategori(){
        return $this->hasMany("App\Models\Kategori","kategori_id","yazi_id");
    }
}
```

My function to retrieve all related datas;

```
$yazilar=Yazi::all();
foreach ($yazilar as $key => $value) {
  echo $value->kategori."<hr>";
}
```

Composer file is;

```
{
    "require": {
        "slim/slim": "^3.0",
        "slim/twig-view": "^2.5",
        "illuminate/database": "^5.8",
        "respect/validation": "^1.1",
        "slim/csrf": "^0.8.3",
        "slim/flash": "^0.4.0",
        "illuminate/pagination": "^5.8"
    },
    "autoload":{
        "psr-4": {
            "App\\":"app"
        }
    }
}
```

Images are ;
https://i.ibb.co/yqL27C0/index.png - https://i.ibb.co/2cn5jN1/kategoriler.png - https://i.ibb.co/Swv4NBY/yazilar.png - https://i.ibb.co/pRk2tNh/yazimodel.png

Answer (score 0):

I suspect that you need `$value->kategori()->kategori` to firstly get the kategori record and then to get the name column from it.

Comment: I made that changes but still not working. I am getting this error for every loop

Notice: Undefined property: Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Relations\HasMany::$kategori_baslik in D:\xampp\htdocs\Slim3-Blog\app\Controllers\HomeController.php on line 87

kategori_baslik  is column name for the kategory model.


$yazilar=Yazi::all();
        foreach ($yazilar as $key => $value) {
        echo $value->kategori()->kategori_baslik."<hr>";
}